# busybox does not display the throughput value at the end of a FTP session?

Tags: busybox

Why doesn't busybox display the throughput value at the end of a FTP session?
Or it is some version specific?

I typed the below command but I did not get any throughput status.

```
busybox ftpget -v -u user -p Password ip abc.txt abc.txt
```

Could anybody please let me know how I can get the throughput value for upload/download data transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Busybox contains very slimmed versions of commands for used in embedded systems. Have you checked that the Busybox ftpget even calculates the throughput?

Ps. I think this question belongs at superuser.com rather than here.

Comment: then wat is the use of running a tput session if we don;t know the tput at the end ..